# Error React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

При запуске чистого проекта(`react-native init AwesomeProject`) возникает ошибка

```
E/unknown:React: Exception in native call from JS
             com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
              Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
/unknown:React: Exception in native call
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling function: RCTDeviceEventEmitter:emit
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Empty Optional cannot be unwrapped
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Error calling function: AppRegistry:runApplication
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Empty Optional cannot be unwrapped
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                 at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196) 
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Скрины прикладываю[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте запустить в отдельном окне терминала команду `npm start` из папки проекта - она запустит дев-сервер, про который говорится в ошибке.

Comment: К сожалению не помогло... Вначале написало `React packager ready` , а потом `[2017-01-19 16:44:06] <START> Building Haste Map
[2017-01-19 16:44:06] <END>   Building Haste Map (47ms)
[2017-01-19 16:44:06] <END>   Initializing Packager (5147ms)
`

Comment: Это нормально. Оставьте это окно открытым и попробуйте перезапустить приложение. Кстати, у вас симулятор или реальный девайс?

Comment: На эмуляторе работает, а на реальном устройстве нет

Answer (score 0):

нужно кэш сбросить браузера: react-native start --reset-cache.